# How to take data from one dataframe and copy it into existing columns in another dataframe based on the shared ID of a third column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So what I have is two different data frames: the one I've been working on (df1) and the one with all the new data I need to put in the first one (df2). Df1 has several columns of zeroes, waiting for the data to be added in. Df2 has the data I need, and several more rows and columns that I don't care about beyond that data. Here is a small subset of the type of data I'm working with.

This is my first time posting my data so I hope I'm doing it right. Let me know if you need a different format.

df1:

```
structure(list(season = c(" FA15", " FA15", " FA15", " FA15", 
" FA15", " FA15", " FA15", " FA15", " FA15", " FA15"), year = c("2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015"), territory.name = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), plot = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), color.band = c("APGBY", 
"APGGU", "APGPW", "APGPW", "APGR", "APGUO", "APGUO", "APGUO", 
"APGUO", "APGYR")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

df2:

```
structure(list(bandnum = c(157328052, 160379101, 157328094, 151313455, 
170364680, 160379104, 151373458, 157328066, 160379103, 160379105
), project = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("*ISSJ", "ISSJ"), class = "factor"), color.band = c("PAWR", 
"WYWAR", "APGP", "APGO", "ABYG", "URYAR", "APBW", "WABG", "OBWAR", 
"GBGAR"), sex = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("?", "F", "M"), class = "factor"), age = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("AHY", "ASY", 
"HY", "N", "SY"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've been chewing on this problem for a few days, trying different things and reading so many answers on stack overflow, but I'm failing to come up with a clear answer on how to take data from one dataframe and copy it into existing columns in another dataframe based on the shared ID of a third column.

Pretty much, I want r to see that both data frames have in the color.band column a listing for the band ABCDEF, and then take the value from df2$bandnum in the same row as ABCDEF and copy it to df1$bandnum in the ABCDEF row there.

I don't want to copy rows that are in df2 but not df1 into df1. I want to mark entries that exist in df1 but not df2 as N/A in the bandnum column.

Column names and data format for color band and band number have been standardized between the two data frames so everything should line up.
What I have so far with code is this:

```
> practicedf <- left_join(x=df1, y=df2, by = "color.band", all.x = TRUE) 
%>% mutate(y = ifelse(is.na(df1$color.band), df1$bandnum, df1$color.band)) %>% select(df2$bandnum)
```

left_join seems to be the right one because it keeps all rows in the left (df1) data frame and only matching rows from the right (df2) data frame.
I get this error though:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = c("APGBY", "APGGU", "APGPW", : 
replacement has 1261 rows, data has 2559
```

color.band is a character vector while bandnum is numerical, is that a problem? What could be the problem here?

---

**Edit:** I had an error with having the column bandnum in both dataframes so I changed df2$bandnum to bandnum.y. My code is now

```
df1_test <- left_join(x=df1, y=df2, by = "color.band") %>% mutate(y =
 ifelse(is.na(color.band), bandnum, color.band)) %>% select(bandnum.y)
```

but when I view(df1_test) it only shows me the column bandnum.y and it's not the same number of entries as my original df1

Here's a subset of df1_test (not the whole thing because it's 2600 entries)

Any way I can make it show the rest of my data as well?

```
structure(list(bandnum.y = c("171324972", "171324972", "171324972", 
"178324697", "178324697", "178324697", "178324697", "178324697", 
"178324697", "178324697", "170364505", "170364505", "170364505", 
"170364505", "170364505", "170364505", NA, "178324692", "178324692", 
"178324692")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: In your `ifelse` you are getting the values from `df1`.  Instead it would be without the `df1$` because the columns are already in the joined dataset and because you used `all.x = TRUE`, it can have more number of rows than the original dataset 'df1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot use the original dataset 'df1' columns after the join becuase it is a `left_join`.  In `tidyverse`, we specify the unquoted column names.  There is no `all.x` argument in `left_join`.  It should be from `merge`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(x=df1, y=df2, by = "color.band") %>% 
     mutate(y = ifelse(is.na(color.band), bandnum, color.band))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error from there that says "Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x The column `bandnum` doesn't exist." even though bandnum exists in df1 and df2 as columns. Why might this be?

Comment: @SarahHays From your example, only 'df2' shows 'bandnum' and there is no 'bandnum' in 'df1'.  If both datasets have 'bandnum' then, you may need to remove one of that column from one of them.  Otherwise, it will change to `bandnum.x` and `bandnum.y`

Comment: Thank you! One more question- it ran and spat out a column full of band numbers when I ran view(df2) but none of my other columns are there. How do I keep those as well?

Comment: @SarahHays You may need to assign the output to a new object if that is what your comment meant i.e. `out <- left_join(df1, df2, ...`

Comment: Hmm, I did that and it still didn't work, should I update with the problem code?

Comment: @SarahHays yes, it would be helpful to understand the reason

Comment: @SarahHays From your example data, I don't find any issues in that direction

Comment: @SarahHays okay, you are using `select` as the last step.  Then, it will select only that column.  REmove it and then you will have all columns.  I was thinking that you need only the 'bandnum' column.  May be that `select` was used as some kind of output checks and later forgot to remove those

Answer (score 1):

`left_join` does not have `all.x = TRUE` that is part of base R `merge`.

You could do the following in base R :

```
df1_test <- transform(merge(df1, df2, by = "color.band", all.x = TRUE), 
                      y = ifelse(is.na(color.band), bandnum, color.band))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I don't get you wrong, you want to update an old df (df1) with information from a new df (df2).
In `data.table`, you can try this:

```
libraty(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
update.vars = intersect(names(df1), names(df2))  # update only common variables

df1[df2, c(update.vars) := df2[,update.vars, with=FALSE], on= 'color.band']
```

Generally this should work. But in the given data the 'merge' ids (`color.band` column) are not unique, which may affect the results.